# Tomcat7 server stops fails to start while using UseParallelGC

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm

I am trying to tune JVM heapsize and garbage collection with setenv.sh file. But when i use UseParallelGC for garbage collection and restart tomcat server, it doesn't start and gives fail status.
My setenv.sh file code is following:

1. export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xms256m"
2. export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xmx2048m"
3. export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"
4. export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -XX:+UseParallelGC"
5. export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError - XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -3 %p' -XX:HeapDumpPath=/path/to/copy"

Comment: what is the exit / exception message on startup ?

Comment: Which JVM?  Both the version number and vendor please `java -version`

Comment: @Edwin BuckL: java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.1) (7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.14.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)